# Spring Data - Converting List<ListenableFuture<EntityWriteResult<Some_class>>> to Future<List<EntityWriteResult<Some_class>>>

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to convert:

```
List<ListenableFuture<EntityWriteResult<Some_Class>>>
```

to:

```
Future<List<EntityWriteResult<Some_Class>>>
```

I am trying to run multiple async inserts for cassandra using:

```
asyncCassandraTemplate.insert(some_object, insertOptions)
```

but this returns `ListenableFuture<EntityWriteResult<Some_Class>>`. I am adding all these to an arraylist, but I need to do the above conversion so that I could ensure completion of all the threads just by calling `get()` on the `Future<List<EntityWriteResult<Some_Class>>>` object i get after conversion.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just iterate over the all elements and call `.get` on them?

Comment: Imagine returning `List<ListenableFuture<EntityWriteResult<Some_Class>>>` from a DAL service and then keep on iterating over them in classes where the data is required.

 Apparently, `Futures.successfulAsList` will take only `List<ListenableFuture<Some_class>>` as input and convert it to `Future<List<Some_class>>` but as `asyncCassandraTemplate.insert(some_object, insertOptions)` returns `ListenableFuture<EntityWriteResult<Some_Class>>` unlike `asyncCassandraTemplate.insert(some_object)` which returns `ListenableFuture<Some_Class>` and I need to use insert options.

Comment: `List<CompletableFuture<EntityWriteResult<Some_class>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();`
`list.forEach(listEle -> futuresOfBayAisleLocators.add( asyncCassandraTemplate.insert(listEle, insertOptions).completable() ));`

`return CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]))
                .thenApply(v -> {
                    return futures.stream()
                            .map(future -> future.join())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                });`
`thenApply` will block until all futures complete, won't it?but faster?